# How to stop WP API endpoint from caching?

Tags: api, cache, rest-api, endpoints

I have a simple endpoint. Its GET, I pass it an ID parameter and it uses this ID to make a curl call.  The endpoint then responds with a couple pieces of info json_encoded.

The issue is that this endpoint keeps caching its results.   How do I keep this from happening?

Couple notes:

1. No caching plugins installed
2. WP config doesn't note caching

The endpoint code is pretty simple:

```
// Get Number of people in line
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'cc/v1', '/in_line/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
           'methods' => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
           'callback' => 'in_line',
           'args' => [
                'id'
            ],
    ) );
} );

function in_line($data) {

  //Do a bunch of Curl stuff

  $response['queue'] = $number;
  $response['queueID'] = $data['id'];

  return json_encode($response);
}
```

I call the endpoint via jQuery ajax.

Comment: As far as I'm aware the REST API doesn't cache its results. Your code mentions "Do a bunch of Curl stuff". Are you sure *that's* not cached?

Comment: How do you know its cached, and where is it cached?

Answer (score 4):

If you have access to your request header you can add the line.
`Cache-Control: private` or `Cache-Control: no-cache`. This will force well-behaved hosts to send you fresh results.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a new instance from `WP_REST_Response` to set the Cache-Control value.

```
<?php
// Get Number of people in line
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'cc/v1', '/in_line/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
           'methods' => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
           'callback' => 'in_line',
           'args' => [
                'id'
            ],
    ) );
} );

function in_line($data) {

  //Do a bunch of Curl stuff

  $response['queue'] = $number;
  $response['queueID'] = $data['id'];

  $result = new WP_REST_Response($response, 200);

  // Set headers.
  $result->set_headers(array('Cache-Control' => 'no-cache'));

  return $result;
}
```

Comment: Rather than setting the cache header manually, it is preferable to use `wp_get_nocache_headers()`. This will set the nocache headers used by WordPress Core. This ensures compatibility with a wider array of hosting environments.

Batcache for example (which is used by a lot of hosts) will look for a `max-age` value, and only if it is set will bypass cache.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @fränk 's comment the correct and more elegant way will be like this:

```php
<?php
// Get Number of people in line
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'cc/v1', '/in_line/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
           'methods' => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
           'callback' => 'in_line',
           'args' => [
                'id'
            ],
    ) );
} );

function in_line($data) {

  //Do a bunch of Curl stuff

  $response['queue'] = $number;
  $response['queueID'] = $data['id'];

  nocache_headers();

  $result = new WP_REST_Response($response, 200);

  return $result;
}
```